# how to save "bmp" as bmp file in sd card?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-ndk, bitmapfactory

Now I'm trying to get a frame picture from video file
and I know how to do it(with `ffmpeg` or `getFrameAtTime` function)

so I can get a frame as bmp structure in my program
but when I save this as `png` or `jpeg`,

these quality are not good although video's quality is fine

so I wanna save this bmp without any **compress**

from what I hear **`copyPixelsToBuffer`** function works for this 
but I couldn't do it... T_T...

please anyone can explain to me how to use this??
//my recording size is (1280, 720)

should I record a video in more bigger size?
or should I save frame as bitmap in sd card???

without compress???

//my guess is it's for compression. compress is a kind of trade off with quality

now I used this function to make a png or jpeg 
**`Bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos)`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics

> Portable Network Graphics (PNG  /ˈpɪŋ/[2] ping) is a bitmapped image
>   format that employs lossless data compression.

The PNG compression you're doing with the code you show is not losing any quality. PNGs are lossless.

What is most likely happening is that the implementation to get the bitmap object into your memory is losing some pixels somewhere.

I suggest you (for comparison and testing purposes) to show the bitmap object in an ImageView full screen on your application and compare it with the saved PNG. Just to check which conversion is really losing quality.

Comment: really thank you for quick reply :D

it was my mistake, quality of video was bad too

I think I have to find any way to upgrade video quality